# Cannot use setText() method in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, settext

I inserted a text field and now I just want it to say "working" within the text field.  I do not have any errors, but when the display comes up the text field is empty. The first line of the code below was generated by netbeans.  I wrote the second line.

```
 private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
      jTextField1.setText("working");
 }
```

Comment: This code is only called if you press the enter key when the caret is within the JTextField. Please go through the Swing tutorials, and you can find the link within the [Swing Info link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: `setText("working");` This could imply a long running task is underway. Two tips: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do that in the wrong method --> `jTextField1ActionPerformed`

try moving this to a OnClickEvent or in the **initComponents** of the App

```
jTextField1.setText("working");
```